# Java MongoDB – Find objects that contain a certain string returning no results

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql

I'm using java's mongodb driver and trying to get all items where the "text" contains the term "Example". However, it just returns no items, no matter what I try. Even using "a" instead of "Example" (which 100% is included in most results) returns 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
db.getCollection("Items").find(in("text", "Example"))
```

Also tried passing a List instead of "Example", which also didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using collections a solution could look like this one:

```
db.getCollection("Items").find(Filters.in("text", ".*Example.*"));
```

You need a regex because (from the JavaDoc) `in`:

```
Creates a filter that matches all documents where the value of a field **equals** any value in the list of specified values.
```